# BIRT- converting table to grid

Tags: birt

Currently I'm working over a birt report with a table to display data. Now, i want to convert the same thing to grid, which provides better viewing and analysing capability. So, is there any easy way (in editing the XML or something) to convert the whole table to grid? Meanwhile, the complete data remains the same.

NB: I havn't yet used a bit with grid, never ever! Also m bit newbie to birt. So pardon me if I'm spiting out anything rubbish.

Comment: I have answered this question, I suggest that what you want to do is look for a solution to create the layout you want using a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table is a different element from a grid.  There is not a button to push that will convert one to the other.  You would need to add a grid element to your report and set it up like you want it to look.

I seriously doubt you want to do this though. a grid will only display the first record returned, unlike a table that will display all the records returned.

Answer (score 1):

A related, but more reasonable question is how to convert a single-column table to a list or vice-versa.

I often need this table-to-list conversion for optimizing master-detail reports for (our customized version of) the WordEmitter, because this prevents superfluous nested tables in the Word output.

Fortunately, for tables without grouping this is relatively easy by editing the XML:
Change the corresponding opening and closing  tag to a  tag, remove the  elements and the  elements (but keep theirs contents).

Apart from that, James' is right: There is no reason to convert a table to a grid item, mainly because a table will display all records (while a grid displays only the first) while the table has all features of a grid (and more, like grouping).